# How to get a list of files that do not match a regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I need help creating a Windows batch script for listing files that do not match this regular expression in a given directory:

```
^[0-9]{5}\s[A-Z].*$
```

Example:

Output should be the file names: `ABC_12345.txt` and `123456-ABC.pdf` and `1234 NO.doc`.

But the file name `12345 ABC.txt` should not be output by the batch script.

Furthermore, if would be awesome if the script could export the list to file `C:\temp\DoesNotMatch.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINDSTR** can be used to filter the output of **DIR** to get the wanted list:

```
@dir /A-D /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V /C:"^[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789] [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" >C:\temp\DoesNotMatch.txt
```

**DIR** outputs because of `/A-D` just files (attribute not directory) in current directory in bare format because of option `/B` which means only file name with file extension, but without file path. Run in a command prompt window `dir /?` for help on this command and its options.

This output of **DIR** is redirected to **FINDSTR** with redirection operator `|`. Please read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for details.

**FINDSTR** runs case-insensitive because of `/I` a regular expression search because of `/R` for lines matching the expression specified in double quotes with option `/C:` and outputs the inverted result because of option `/V` which means the lines on which the regular expression matched no string.

The option `/C:"..."` must be used here to specify the string being interpreted because of `/R` as regular expression instead of literal string as otherwise on using just `"..."` the space character would be interpreted as separator between two regular expression search strings which would be OR applied on each line.

The regular expression search string looks a bit strange because of the regular expression syntax supported by **FINDSTR** is very limited. Run in a command prompt window `findstr /?` for help on this command and its options and regular expression support. I recommend reading additionally [SS64 - FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) and [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/3074564)

`^` ... means beginning of line which is beginning of file name because of no file path output.

`[0-9]` could be used, but matches also `¹`, `²`, `³`. For that reason `[0123456789]` is used to really match only any of those 10 digit characters.

A multiplier like `{5}` is not supported by **FINDSTR**. For that reason it is necessary to write the digit character class definition five times in the search expression.

The character class `\s` matching any whitespace character according to Unicode standard is not supported by **FINDSTR**. But vertical whitespaces are not allowed or very unusual in file names, horizontal tab character is not allowed in a file name, no-break space would be possible in a file name, but is also not very usual. And the special characters with Unicode code values U+1680, U+180E, U+2000 to U+2008 are most likely also never used in file names. So `\s` can be replaced by a normal space character.

`[A-Z]` could be used, but matches also lots of other characters like `ÄäÖöÜü` to list just a few here. So it is better to use `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]` to match case-insensitive only the ASCII characters.

The output of **FINDSTR** is redirected with `>` into the file `C:\temp\DoesNotMatch.txt` which is overwritten in case of existing already on executing the batch file with this single command line.